# Oracle database connection - without using setUrl

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection, datasource

I am trying to use a datasource to get connection to Oracle database.

I am setting the OracleConnectionCacheImpl object with properties like driverType, networkProtocol, user, password, databaseName, serverName, portNumber.

setUrl cannot be used.

What should I do to get a connection like in the case, if the following url is used ?

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)
>               (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1) (PORT=1521))
>               (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2) (PORT=1521))
>               (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))

I hope I made some sense in what I told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RAC, you need to set the URL.
In my experience, if you do not set the URL explicitly, it will not work in this case.
I am unable to comment, hence posting a new reply.